# Updating an existing excel file through Python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, pycharm

I tried running this program many times but the existing excel file doesn't get updated. Can someone guide me through the correct process? Thank you for your help!

```
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl as pl
manifest_df = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\dhruvjadhav\PycharmProjects\Alpha\PassengerManifest.xlsx')
manifest_df['Current Balance'] = manifest_df['Balance'] - manifest_df['Fare']
print(manifest_df)
filename = (r'C:\Users\dhruvjadhav\PycharmProjects\Alpha\PassengerManifest.xlsx')
wb = pl.load_workbook(filename)
ws = wb.worksheets[0]
for ws in wb.worksheets:
    print(ws.title)
with pd.ExcelWriter("PassengerManifest.xlsx", engine="openpyxl", mode="a") as writer:
    manifest_df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="ws.title")
writer.save()
```

Comment: Dhruv Jadhav can you tell what are you trying achieve with this code ?

Comment: add a column to an excel sheet containing the answers after performing an arithmetic operation on 2 columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to update an existing excel, you can use the following code. Just pandas is needed.

```
import pandas as pd

# read the xlsx file
manifest_df = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\dhruvjadhav\PycharmProjects\Alpha\PassengerManifest.xlsx')
# perform arithmentic operation
manifest_df['Current Balance'] = manifest_df['Balance'] - manifest_df['Fare']
# write again the excel file
manifest_df.to_excel(r'C:\Users\dhruvjadhav\PycharmProjects\Alpha\PassengerManifest.xlsx', index=False)
```

That's it

Comment: Glad to help you. If the answer is the correct one, please mark it. thank you